# Merge, Combine, Join 2 different rows in 1 single row Google SQL | Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
| post_state | total_posts |
| opened     | 1000        |
| completed  | 2000        |
```

I'm using this query to get the above result:

```
SELECT post_state,
    SUM(total_threads) as total_posts,
    FROM data.table
    WHERE post_state IN ('opened', 'completed')
    GROUP BY post_state
```

However, I would like to combine both rows in a single one, something like this:

```
| post_state | total_posts |
| all_posts  | 3000        |
```

How am I able to output this in Google SQL?
I'm new to SQL world, happy if you could help me out :)

Thanks in advance for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `GROUP BY post_state`:

```
SELECT 
  'all_posts' as post_state,
  SUM(total_threads) as total_posts,
FROM data.table
WHERE post_state IN ('opened', 'completed')
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you Sergey!

Answer (score 1):

Another option

```
SELECT 
  'all_posts' as post_state,
  SUM(IF(post_state IN ('opened', 'completed'), total_threads, 0)) as total_posts,
FROM data.table
```